# Alternative to typoetools TypeResolver library

Tags: java, types, reflection

I am working on a project in which we are using `typetools` library and when we've tried to upgrade to Java 17 it broke because of this library, it seems it's not supported anymore and something's going one with newest Java versions.
Therefore we are aiming to find an alternative but I haven't had any success so far. I tried some other libraries or even with Java reflection.

This is the code where we are using it so maybe someone here can give me an alternative or think any other way to do it.

```
private static class Listener<T extends IEvent> {
    /**
     * The consumer method
     */
    private final Consumer<T> consumer;

    /**
     * The argument type of the consumer
     */
    private final Class<?> argumentType;

    /**
     * Default constructor
     *
     * @param consumer The consumer to store
     */
    private Listener(final Consumer<T> consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;

        // determine the parameter type
        final Class<?>[] typeArgs = TypeResolver.resolveRawArguments(Consumer.class, consumer.getClass());
        argumentType = typeArgs[0];
    }

    public Consumer<T> getConsumer() {
        return consumer;
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether this listener should be notified about the event passed as parameter or not
     *
     * @param event The event to check the compatibility with
     * @return True if the listener's argument is compatible with the event received as parameter, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isCompatibleWith(final IEvent event) {
        return argumentType.isAssignableFrom(event.getClass());
    }
}
```

Everything happens in these 2 lines:
final Class<?>[] typeArgs = TypeResolver.resolveRawArguments(Consumer.class,
consumer.getClass());
argumentType = typeArgs[0];

What we achieve here is extracting the class given in the diamond operator of `Consumer<T> consumer`

Comment: There never was a guaranty that you can extract the actual type of a `Consumer<T>`. Just add a `Class<T>` parameter and change the caller to pass `XYZ.class`. Since the constructor is `private`, all callers must be in the same compilation unit, which makes it easy to find and adapt them. As a bonus, the code will be more efficient and not rely on a 3rd party library.

Comment: I cannot change it that easily without a big refactoring. This ends up being called by something like `eventBus.subscribe(this::onCatchEvent);` being `onCatchEvent` a method itself.